# Modeling using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, model, modeling

I'm using c# and mongoDB I have more experience with system that uses databases as the back end, I'm trying to understand and change my mindset and start to stop thinking in terms of database modeling and try to think more in how to model in NoSql.

I'm going to explain a small DB Schema and what I'd like to know how that translates to mongoDB.

This is a typical case for a freelance website:(just a very small case just to get the idea)
the site is going to contain four different type of users in the system like Sales representatives, Administrators, Users, Companies, etc,

The Users are going to be able to post their profile with different types of media content like an Image, Website, Document, etc they can apply to jobs posted from a company, the users can have friends as well which are going to be users.

```
tables:
 -Users
       1to1 -Roles
       1to1 -Candidate       
                       1toM -MediaFile (for the profile)
                                       1to1 -MediaType (file, web, etc)
                       1toM - JobApplications - Mto1 Job (many to many relationship)
       1to1 -Company
                       1toM Jobs
       1toM - Friends (Users)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample mongodb schema:

```
User
{
   _id: 1,
   Roles : [],
   Candidate: {
      HourlyRate: "0.00",
      Portfolio: [
         {
            Title: "",
            MediaFiles: [
              {
                Type: "File"
              }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
Company: {
     Id: "1",
     Name: ""
   },
Friends: [
    {
      Id: "1",
      FullName: ""
    }
   ]
}


Company
{
  _id: "1",
  Name: ""
}

Job
{
  _id: "1",
  Title: ""
}

Application
{
  _id: "1",
  JobId: "1",
  UserId: "1",
  ApplicantFullName: ""
}
```

Some basic rules:

1. Embedd as much as you can. It is improve read performance and allow to read data in a single request to the database. The choice embedd or not is usually made on how data will grow, change over time and how you gonna query it. In your case we embedded Friends (I assumed that  it will not be very big collection, since freelancers site is not facebook :)). We also embedded portfolio items and media files into the User Profile, the portfolio usually will not be more than 10
2. Consider de-normalization of data for fast querying.  In our case I assumed that we will need to display some friends on freelancer profile, that's why I denormalized FullName. Also I think you will be always showing company associated with user profile, that's why we denormalized ComanyName into user.

Some notes:

1. Denormalization always add some overhead to writes, but increase read speed. For your case I assumed will be more reads than writes and heavily used denormalization.
2. When reading data consider excluding fields from object when you no need them. For example when you need display list of freelancers and don't really care about Friends, Portfolio -- exclude them.   It will decrease amount of data need to be transferred between db and app and speed up deserialization.

What's next? Go through [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) available on mongodb site. Consider visit mongodb conference or local mongodb group meetup.

Hope that help!

Comment: thanks @Andrew Orsich, I was thinking about to separate the profile from the candidate entity but so practically is better to have as much embedded/denormalized resources as possible and then perform partial reads?